# Javascript error: Error: ta is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to add a character counter to a text field using this code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.txtclass').keypress(function(){
      ta = $(this);
      if(ta.val().length >= 350){
          ta.val( ta.val().substr(0, 350) );
      } else {
          $("#counter span").text(350-ta.val().length);
      }
  });
});

setInterval('$("#counter span").text(350-ta.val().length);', 350);
```

I get that JavaScript error:  `"Error: ta is not defined"` and points me to that specific line in my code.

Any insight into whats happening and how to fix it would be really appreciated as I'd like to add more counters for other text-fields into the website elsewhere.

Edit: here's the html for the counter

```
 <div id="counter"><span>350</span> characters remaining.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `ta` to be? Where is it defined?

Comment: If 350-ta is an input element's id, then use $("#350-ta").val().length inside of your call to text(). If not, please include the HTML markup you're attempting to manipulate.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this onkeyup from the textbox?

Comment: SOrry about that, I added the html markup, does that help?

Comment: And I added the full javascript :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means just what it says. The value being passed to the `text` method is the result of the expression `350 - ta.va().length`. The variable `ta` has not been defined at the point this code is being run.

A few things to note before my proposed solution.

1. You are correct in responding to the keypress event to truncate the user input, but there is no need to use an interval to update the count - just update it in the event handler.
2. Don't put the function passed to `setInterval` in quotes. This causes it to be run through `eval`, which is both slower and less secure.
3. Save jQuery objects in variables outside of the event handler so the same objects can be used each time the handler is invoked. This uses less memory and should be a tiny bit faster.

Here's how I would implement this:

```
$(function () {
  var ta = $(".txtclass"),
      counter = $("#counter span");

  ta.keypress(function () {
    var taValue = ta.val();

    if (taValue.length >= 350) {
      taValue = ta.val(taValue.slice(0, 350)).val();
    }

    counter.text(taValue.length);
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for writing the only answer that makes any sense for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @James - unless you count my answer, which was posted first (though is less thorough than Jimmy's - it's a pain to type code from a smart phone, and since I answered the question has been updated with more info).

Comment: @nnnnnn - Very true, I apologise :) Although you're right, this answer is more thorough and covers things like the fact you really shouldn't be passing a string to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

What is `350-ta` - this isn't supported as a valid value in this construct, wrap quotes around it as `"350-ta"`, but then that won't work with val, so if this is an ID, do `$("350-ta")`.

Comment: I think it's meant to be 350 - ta.val().length (as in, a subtraction, not an identifer). I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function () {
    $("#counter span").text($("#350-ta").val().length);
}, 350);
```

I'm not sure what 350-ta is so I assumed it was an id... I put your set Interval logic in a callback function so it was more readable. Also .val() needs to be called against a query object

If 350-ta is supposed to be a calculation where ta is a string value then you might be looking for `350 - ta.length`

Answer (score 1):

This is an invalid JS statement. Use:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  $("#counter span").text(/* whatever that retieves a string*/) 
}, 350);
```

I have no idea how do you need to calculate the text, but que setTimeout part works lika that

Answer (score 1):

Your variable ta must not be defined. I assume it should be defined to refer to the text area in question, so add this on the line before:

```
var ta = $("#theIdOfYourTextareaGoesHere");
```

Then the code run by your set Interval will have a reference to the text area so it can get its length.